# Safari doesn't set content-length when using xmlhttprequest

Tags: wcf, safari, xmlhttprequest, http-content-length

I have a Javascript object that i am trying to post to the server with XMLHttpRequest() using JSON.stringify().  my code works fine in all major browsers except for Safari (5.1.2).  My analysis shows that Safari, is in fact sending the data.  i can see the message in the Safari Developer Tools and i see the bytes received in the IIS logs and it seems accurate (48kb) but the WCF function doesn't get the object data.  In looking into the wcf logs i see that the content-length is 0 for safari and has a value for chrome.  Does anyone have any insight to this issue?

SAFARI:

```
<httprequest>
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>keep-alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>0</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>application/json</Content-Type>
<Accept>*/*</Accept>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
<Accept-Language>en-US</Accept-Language>
<Authorization>Negotiate TlRMTVNTUA</Authorization>
<Cookie>ASP.NET_SessionId=2ynxibj2jovjo345nckpsskm</Cookie>
<Host>localhost</Host>
<Referer>http://localhost/xRMS.Net/PROFILE/Employee.htm?winid=flENz4mLt1TRBTvL&theme=ThemeDevelopment.css</Referer>
<User-Agent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7</User-Agent>
<Origin>http://localhost</Origin>
</WebHeaders>
</httprequest>
```

CHROME:

```
<httprequest>
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>keep-alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>48822</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>application/json</Content-Type>
<Accept>*/*</Accept>
<Accept-Charset>ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3</Accept-Charset>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip,deflate,sdch</Accept-Encoding>
<Accept-Language>en-US,en;q=0.8</Accept-Language>
<Cookie>ASP.NET_SessionId=gapksa2mmuh3wcrntz32mipw</Cookie>
<Host>localhost</Host>
<Referer>http://localhost/xRMS.Net/PROFILE/Employee.htm?winid=FTWLXL4b8aTWaaaM&theme=ThemeDevelopment.css</Referer>
<User-Agent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2</User-Agent>
<Origin>http://localhost</Origin>
</WebHeaders>
</httprequest>
```

Comment: So, to add a little more info.  if i change the url to be http://server.domain.com/website ;  it works correctly however if the url is http://server/website  it doesn't send the header.

Comment: A note to modern readers arriving here: the current latest version (Safari 10) ***appears*** to never send the `Content-Length` header (it doesn't show up in the "Request Headers" section of the network tab), but if you log the headers received on the server side you will realise that it actually does send it. The Safari dev tools just don't report the Content-Length header for some reason. (Yes, this is misleading and unhelpful.) If you're reading this in 2016 then you *probably don't* have the same problem as the OP here did.